# mouse over css sprite

Tags: html, css, css-sprites

I have an anchor like this:

```
<a href="#">
   <i class="ico01"></i>
   <span>Text</span>
</a>
```

ico01 applies an image with CSS sprite. I would like to change the background color of the anchor content (span + i) on mouse over, however it just applies to the text (span). Is there any trick that I`m missing?

Here`s a JS Fiddle. I need the background not only in the span, but also wrapping the image:

https://jsfiddle.net/0esbmusq/1/

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't change the background color of image... but you need to change background-position for that

Comment: Could you add some more code, maybe a running example snippet?

Comment: jsfiddle available. I didn`t put initially because of the sprite, but I could setup one for sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
a{
   display:block;
}
```

```css
.ico01 {
  background: url('https://download.seaicons.com/icons/marcus-roberto/google-play/512/Google-Chrome-icon.png') no-repeat -10px -24px;
  width: 492px;
  height: 488px;
  display:block;
}
a{
  display:block;
}
a:hover {
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <span>Google</span>
  <i class="ico01"></i>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
a {
  display:block;
}


a:hover {
background-color:black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean?

```css
a:hover span{background-color:black};
```

```html
<a href="#">
   <i class="ico01"></i>
   <span>Text</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Please review the question?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use display:block for link.